# Solenoid stroke limits

Tags: mechanical-engineering, actuator

Im new to rotary solenoids and I had like to understand the definition of stroke.

For example, some rotary solenoid has in its technical information a parameter called stroke options and it says 25-45 degrees.

[image]

Here is a link to some example - [link](https://www.testco-inc.com/ledex#rotary)

Does it mean that the solenoid has a maximum rotation of 25 or 45 degrees but I can also use limits of +-10 for example it will have to be +- 25/45 degrees?

Thank you.

Comment: added an image above, thank you.

Comment: This table doesn't help us answer your question all that much.  Post a link to the datasheet.  Or the manual.  Or, at least, post a link to where that table came from.

Comment: added a link as example